# Multiplying a Curve by a Plane

Tags: functional-analysis, matrix-calculus

Is there a field of mathematics that considers multiplying functions in a manner analogous to matrix multiplication? For instance,

1. Let $\mathbf{x}$ is an $n$-dimensional vector such that $x_i=\sin(2\pi \frac {i} {n}))$, for $i=1,\ldots, n$.
2. Let $\mathbf{A}$ be an $n\times n$ matrix where $A_{i,j}=\cos(4\pi \frac {i} {n} - 2\pi \frac {j} {n})$ for each $i,j$.
3. Let $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}$ so that $y_i=\frac 1 2 \sin(4\pi \frac {i} {n})$.

If we imagine $n$ going to infinity, then we can define an operator, $\text{prod_fcn}$, such that $\text{prod_fcn}(x(t), A(t, s)) = y(t)$. This example is illustrated graphically below:
[image]

Obviously this is just one simple example of a curve being "warped" by a plane. I'm curious to know if this sort of functional operation is a commonly studied thing. If so, any information about this would be appreciated.

Comment: How familiar are you with functional analysis? Much of it deals with linear operators on infinite-dimensional spaces, which is a direct generalization of multiplication of vectors by matrices (not by "planes", of course). Very often, these infinite dimensional linear operators can be approximated by matrix multiplication.

Comment: Not very...my background is in statistics. Good lead though. And of course, the "planes" part was misleading. I just needed the title to sound catchier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as if you are missing a factor $1/n$?. But otherwise,
your matrix sum corresponds
to a discrete approximation of the following integral operator:
$$ L \phi(y) = \int_0^1 k(y,x) \phi(x) \; dx $$
where $\phi(x)=\sin(2\pi x)$ and $k(y,x) = \cos(2\pi(2y-x))$. An operator of the above form and with continuous (even better $C^1$) kernel $k(y,x)$ has very nice properties, in particular may be well approximated by the discrete matrix version as in your example.

More general versions are in $L^2$ where you are dealing with [Hilbert-Schmidt integral operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%E2%80%93Schmidt_integral_operator). But you have to be more careful when approximating by a matrix.

One may construct [Fredholm determinant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_determinant) for such operators (which in the continuous case, you may easily approximate by your matrix version). This enables to calculate e.g. eigenvalues for the operator.

You may also have a look at [Integral transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_transform).

These are just some examples of the use of the limiting case of your matrix multiplication.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. The integral transform is the most obvious match for my problem. And clearly it has tons of applications.